# athena presto - Filter based on multiple nested struct

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Here is the data structure:

```
TEST: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TEST2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

What I would like to do is filter my entire table when `TEST2.title = 'A'`

I'm able to do this for `name` which is at the first level but I have trouble doing this within the second nested array(struct)

This is my solution for filtering on the first level. That may also be inefficient:

select TEST from table
where cardinality(filter(TEST, e -> e.name = 'A')) > 0

NOTE: `any_match` is not available in Athena Presto

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by mapping (`transform`) the outer array to its inner array, at which point you have an array[array[t]]. Then if you call flatten(), it translates an array[array[t]] -> array[t] that you can make decisions on. Should look something like this:

`where cardinality(filter(flatten(transform(test, e -> e.test2)), e -> e.title = 'A')) > 0`